# cannot deploy app on glassfish

Tags: eclipse, web-services, soap, rpc

```
import java.util.List;
import javax.jws.WebMethod;
import javax.jws.WebService;
import javax.jws.soap.SOAPBinding;
import javax.jws.soap.SOAPBinding.Style;

import org.soapwebservice.model.Product;
@WebService
@SOAPBinding(style = Style.RPC)
public interface ProductCatalog {
    @WebMethod(action="fetch_Categories",operationName="fetchCategories")
    List<String> getProductCategories();
    @WebMethod
    List<String> getProducts(String category);
    @WebMethod
    boolean addProduct(String category, String product);
    @WebMethod
    List<Product> getProductsV2(String category);

}
```

This is the code it is failing only when I try to include the  following line

> @SOAPBinding(style = Style.RPC)

and also the the wsdl doesn't change when I try to bind with RPC style.
deploy is failing=Error occurred during deployment: Exception while loading the app : java.lang.IllegalStateException: ContainerBase.addChild: start: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: java.lang.RuntimeException: Servlet web service endpoint '' failure. Please see server.log for more details.